# RabbitPlugin for DGT eboard not displaying complete FEN notation

Tags: java, c, chess, uci, fen

Has anyone worked with RabbitPlugin DLL for the DGT e-board before? 
I am able to detect moving chess pieces from the board and it's giving me an FEN String but it's not giving the complete FEN notation (please see below). Can anyone provide help on how to get the full notation as described here [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation) Thanks

```
rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the DGT board can give you the full FEN string. The other parts of the notation (side to move, castling options, en passant options, move counts) would require the board to have enough internal intelligence to actually follow a game of chess. I believe the board is only able to report the current pieces and their positions, but can't give you any further information about the actual game in progress.